# Unable to replicate in wsl2

Tags: wsl-2

If I copy in the windows11 and paste it into the clion in wsl2.He won't work!!!!.But restarting wsl2 will fix the problem, but it will come back later.

I hope it runs normally. I used to paste it using vscode ssh before.

And,I using ubuntu16.04 in wsl2